# Do index names such as "logstash-YYYY.MM.dd" positively affect searches?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Do index names such as `logstash-YYYY.MM.dd`, `logstash-YYYY.MM`, `logstash-YYYY` positively affect time-based filtering in Kibana?  For example, do having daily indexes avoid Kibana querying shards in indexes whose name falls outside a given time filter?

Googling has determined multiple shards are good for:

1. Distributing searches across multiple nodes
2. Planning the future addition of nodes to achieve 1.

And Logstash-style daily/monthly/yearly indexes are good for:

1. Regularly deleting old documents (since deleting an entire index is cheaper than individually deleting contained documents.)
2. Selectively closing old indexes.

So if I don't need to be able to cycle out (delete/close) old documents, or  plan to have multiple nodes, what benefits do daily/monthly/yearly indexes have?  Do these extra indexes (hence shards) only go to slow down queries?

Answer (score 1):

The most important advantage of having indexes in such a pattern is:-

1. You just define pattern in Kibana & it will pick all the indexes saving you time to put all the indexes manually.
2. For querying in for ex logstash-YYYY.MM.dd index, it will only query this index instead of querying in all indexes thus providing you faster response time.

Comment: 1> This doesn't sound like an advantage over *not* having daily indices.  2> If I explicitly type `GET logstash-2015.07.24/_search` yes, but what about `GET logstash-*/_search?q=@timestamp:[2015-07-24+TO+2015-07-24}`?  What about filtering in Kibana?